# Same Line Commenting on Python with ls

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments, jupyter

I am a student taking my first Python class and am using Anaconda & Jupyter for Python 3. I have read up on commenting and understand they begin with a hash mark ( # ) and whitespace character and continue to the end of the line. It is my understanding that they should not affect the execution of the code.

When I run "ls" in order to display my working directory it runs perfectly fine. However, when I add a comment just above it, it does not run. Can someone please help me understand why this might be? Pictures attached.

This is the error I receive with a comment:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-96a2904231e9> in <module>()
      1 # show working directory
----> 2 ls
NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
```

[image: run 1]
[image: run 2]

Comment: `ls` is not a python command at all. If you run it by itself jupyter might assume you meant the `ls` command from unix system and run it, but everything you add to it (not just #) will make it fail as python code

Comment: `!ls` or `!dir` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, your working on Jupyter with Python kernel and so the `bash` command cannot be used. However, you can use a magic for `bash` such that

```
%%bash
ls
```

or for windows

```
%%cmd
dir
```

One more thing is that I mentioned as a comment, such as:

```
!ls
!dir
```